# How do I Copy files to a USB with apple script that runs on said USB?

Tags: macos, applescript

I run a computer lab at Denver University. We are having an issue with our backup system, and I need to copy/duplicate all of the files on the (Apple) computers onto a USB that I keep at my desk.

At the moment, I need to plug in a USB into each of the computers and manually duplicate each of the items of the "documents" folder and deposit them into a new folder on my USB. I need an Apple Script that I put on my USB, insert my USB into a computer, activate the app, and it will make a new directory named "(User name) upload", and deposit all of the items into that directory. Here is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Finder"
set theFolder to disk / Volumes / Lexar / stuff
set Files1 to Users / matanya / documents
tell application "Finder"
    try
        duplicate file Files1 to theFolder
    on error
        tell application "Finder"
            display dialog "Transfer Failed"
        end tell
    end try
end tell
```

one of the issues is that every time I run the script, I get an error that says the the variable "Volumes" is not defined. Another one is that I am afraid that when I plug this script into another computer, it will not find the folder "matanya" that I have in my directory. Is there a way to call it "home" or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the `Finder` accepts only HFS paths – starting with a **disk** name and colon separated. The folder `Volumes` doesn't matter when using HFS paths.

`path to documents folder` points always to the folder `Documents` of the current user.

```
set theFolder to "Lexar:stuff:"
set documentsFolder to path to documents folder
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists disk "Lexar") then
        display dialog "Insert disk 'Lexar'" buttons "Cancel" default button 1
    end if
    try
        duplicate documentsFolder to folder theFolder
    on error
        display dialog "Transfer Failed"
    end try
end tell
```

More sophisticated this version creates a folder with the short user name of the current user and duplicates the documents folder to that individual folder

```
set theFolder to "Lexar:stuff:"
set currentUser to short user name of (system info)
set documentsFolder to path to documents folder
tell application "Finder"
    if not (exists disk "Lexar") then
        display dialog "Insert disk 'Lexar'" buttons "Cancel" default button 1
    end if
    if not (exists folder currentUser of folder theFolder) then
        make new folder at folder theFolder with properties {name:currentUser}
    end if
    try
        duplicate documentsFolder to folder currentUser of folder theFolder
    on error
        display dialog "Transfer Failed"
    end try
end tell
```

With `launchd` you even could run this script automatically whenever the USB drive is inserted.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me narrow down what was going on. The only issue is that the script still isn't working. The good thing is that I know it fails at the duplicate part of the script. Do I have to send the files to a disk first, and then transfer, or is it a space concern, where it won't duplicate unless I have enough space?

Comment: What is not working? You might print the actual error message rather than just "Failed".

Comment: Sorry, I got it to work. thank you. all that was happening was the files I was trying to transfer were to big for my USB.